# Aggregate works with complete cases

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to aggregate multiple columns by a character vector. However I think that base R aggregate works on complete cases so if a summation variable is missing for one variable it is excluded from all sums. This illustrates the issue

```
v1 <- c(1, 1, 1, NA)
v2 <- c(2, 2, NA, 2)
v3 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B")

df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)

aggregate(.~v3, data=df, FUN=sum)
```

With the output

```
  v3 v1 v2
1  A  1  2
2  B  1  2
```

the outputs I was expecting is

```
  v3 v1 v2
1  A  2  2
2  B  1  4
```

So v1 sums to 3 and v2 sums to 6, as they are in `df`

Is there a change to `aggregate` that I can use to produce my desired output? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aggregate` has an argument `na.action`

> na.action: a function which indicates what should happen when the data
> contain ‘NA’ values. The default is to ignore missing values
> in the given variables.

which gives the result you're expecting when used with `na.pass`

```
aggregate(. ~ v3, df, \(x) sum(x, na.rm=T), na.action=na.pass)
  v3 v1 v2
1  A  2  2
2  B  1  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to replace NAs with 0s:

```r
aggregate(. ~ v3, data = replace(df, is.na(df), 0), FUN = sum)

#   v3 v1 v2
# 1  A  2  2
# 2  B  1  4
```